# Plesk, access all vhosts via default.com/~some-domain.com?

Tags: virtualhost

Is it possible to access vhosts/domains created on server but not directly via domain which is created.

I would like to have access in the form http://www.maindomain.com/~otherdomain.com or similar.

IMPORTANT: I don't want to push users towards editing /etc/hosts file and adding the domain there locally to point to server and so on..

Comment: I was working on an answer, but it had more questions than it did answers. This is possible, can you update the question with your folder layout for the main site and other sites as well. Different answers depending on the folder hierarchy

Comment: ah, it is bit tricky.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For security reasons, I can not recommend to do this.**

However, **you can** manipulate the *default host templates* located in:

```
/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/default/nginxDomainVhost.php
/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/default/domain/domainVirtualHost.php
```

Just run the `httpdmng` utility. This will *recreate* all vhost configuration files based on the template. `/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/httpdmng --reconfigure-all`

Instead of your prefered solution, I recommend you to put the whole damn thang behind a sub domain. Just add it as an alias to every vhost in the template, like `site1.maindomain.com`.

Remember to renew your template manipulations after updates. Don't lock them with `chattr +i` !

Comment: You sure about that? What about symbolic links?

Comment: I've edited my answer.